# How do I install 3rd party lightning component to Salesforce that is in zip file

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-flows

I am trying to install the 'Rich Text Input' lightning component to use it in my Lightning Flow from the following url:
https://sites.google.com/view/flowunofficial/flow-screen-components/rich-text-input?authuser=0

When I click install, it does not take me to Salesforce but rather download  a zip file. How do I install it in my Salesforce after downloading it?

Thanks

Comment: Documentation for installation in shared link says: 'The easiest way to install a component right now is to download the installation file (it's a zip file) from a specific Component page and then follow the installation instructions for using Workbench.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the Installation file, go to the [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com), log in, click on Migration > Deploy, choose the downloaded file, click Next, and finally Deploy. You can use other tools if you prefer, but this is by far the easiest way for now.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for replying. I installed the package using the instructions above. One quick question. How do I check if it is ready for use. It should be visible if I go to setup and Lightning components in Salesforce. Correct?

Comment: @Student As soon as the Workbench deployment status says its done, it's ready. Or, you can check previous deployments in Setup under Deployment Status. And, yes, the component should appear in Setup as well as if you refresh your IDE or Developer Console.

Comment: I checked the deployment status it shows "Validate: Succeeded". How long does it take to show "Deployment:Succeeded"? Its been a long time. Currently, I am not able to find the component installed anywhere. It is not even appearing in lightning flow for use.

Comment: On the workbench side, the status is shown as "Succeeded" and It says the component type: AuraDefinitionBundle and  fileName: mdapioutput/aura/richTextInputFSC , fullName: richTextInputFSC. I don't know how to locate the component. Unable to find it in iightning components.

Comment: Nevermind I will create a new question with this issue. Thanks for the help.